# Converting list of 2-element lists: [[word, length], [word, length], ...]

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, string-length

I need help editing this function lenumerate() that takes a string
(like 's') and returns a list of 2-item lists containing each word and
it's length:`[['But', 3], ['then', 4], ['of', 2], ... ['are', 3], ['nonmigratory', 12]]`

> lenumerate(s) - convert 's' into list of 2-element lists: [[word,
>   length],[word, length], ...]
>
> ```
> # Define the function first ...
> def lenumerate(s):
>
> l = []  # list for holding your result
>
> # Convert string s into a list of 2-element-lists
> ```
>
> *Enter your code here*
>
> ```
> return l
> ```
>
> ... then call the lenumerate() to test it
>
> ```
>  text = "But then of course African swallows are nonmigratory"
>  l = lenumerate(text)
>  print("version 1", l)
> ```

I think I need to spit the list and use the len() function, but I am not exactly sure how to go about using both of those in the most efficient way.

Comment: SO is not meant to post homework questions verbatim...

Comment: First of all, I am only asking for help on this one part. Second, this place is for programming questions and this definitely falls into that category.

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas/homework. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Brandi: If you browse through this network, you will find the Open Letter to Students https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems The idea is to help with *specific* problems.

Comment: Like I said, I figured I had to split the list and use the len function, I just didn't know how to code it. But, don't worry, I am deleting my account since everyone on here just love to bitch at everyone else.

Comment: @Meteorologist: No, I did not even downvote. But it is simply unethical to let others make homework. How can a teacher perform fair grading? As a result the reputation of most academia is degrading, since several people with degrees turn up that demonstrate lack of the skills they are supposed to have mastered.

Comment: How about we recognize that @Meteorologist didn't mean for us to do his HW, just point him in the right direction (as he already said, he knows `split` and `len` are the way to go). He wasn't trying to be unfair, but was just stuck

Comment: This isn't even MY homework. This is a friend's homework who asked me for help, I tried to help, but wasn't able to. However, it kept bugging me so I asked the question on here out of pure curiosity.

Comment: That's fine, I personally think this is a *valid* question. BTW (both of you), try not to discuss in comments, it's meant for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer you want:

```
def lenumerate(s):
    l = []
    words = s.split(' ')

    for word in words:
        l.append([word,len(word)])

    return l
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 def lenumerate(s):

    l = []  # list for holding your result

    for x in s.split(): # split sentence into words using split()
        l.append([x, len(x)]) #append a list to l x and the length of x

    return l
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `list comprehension` here. So:

```
def lenumerate (s): return [[word, len (word)] for word in s.split()]
```

---

Let me explain this nifty one-liner:

1. You can use `def` (or anything that needs a colon) on **one line**. Just keep typing after the colon.
2. List comprehension means you can create a list in a special way. So instead of defining temporary list `l` and adding to it later, I create *and* customize it on the spot by enclosing it in brackets.
3. I make `[word, len (word)]` as you suggested, and Python understands that I will define `word` in my for loop, which:
4. Comes **after** the statement. That's why I first made the list, then my `for` statement
5. And, like you guessed, the list we are cycling through it `s.split()` (splits at spaces)

Any other questions, just ask!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one succinct method:

```
text = "But then of course African swallows are nonmigratory"

def lenumerate(txt):
    s = text.split(' ')
    return list(zip(s, map(len, s)))

# [('But', 3), ('then', 4), ('of', 2), ('course', 6), ('African', 7),
#  ('swallows', 8), ('are', 3), ('nonmigratory', 12)]
```